How to send a copy of the order to the customer in Prestashop 8?
I have a store in Prestashop 8 and would require sending a copy to the customer every time an order is placed. It arrives perfectly to the administrator but not to the client.
As an additional note, the email alerts plugin is correctly configured
Could you help me?
Thanks in advance
